# If $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a monotone decreasing function, $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to+\infty$. Prove,$\sum f(n)$ converges if $\int_1^\infty f $converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

At the first look, I thought that this can be easly done using "Cauchy-Maclaurin Integral Test". But after recalling the statement of the theorem, I found myself wrong. Cauchy Maclaurin Test asserts that

> Let $f$ be a positive, decreasing function on $[1,+\infty]$. Then the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} f(k)$ converges if and only if the improper integral $\displaystyle \int_1^{+\infty} f(t) dt$ converges.

But in the given problem one property of the function $f$ is removed, which is $f$ is positive. And a new condition has been added which is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=0$. And note that we are just asked to prove the "if" part only.
Even it intuitively looks like $f$ is monotone decreasing and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to+\infty$ impliy $f(x)\ge 0 \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$. But can I prove it rigorously? 
Can anybody give me a proof of the statement given in my title part?

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: $f$ decreasing and $f(x) \to 0$ *implies* that $f(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: @MartinR, intuitively it looks like $f(x) \ge 0$ but can you prove it rigorously? Even I am also trying to prove your comment.

Comment: If $f(x_0) < 0$ for some $x_0$, can the limit still be zero?

Comment: @MartinR, ok, if $f$ gives a negetive value at any point, then the limit which is actually infimum of $f$ on $\Bbb{R}$ will be negetive. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$f(x) \to 0$
as $x \to \infty$,
then,
for any $c > 0$
there is an
$x(c)$ such that
$|f(x)| < c$
for $x > x(c)$.

If $f$ is monotone decreasing,
then
$x_2 > x_1$
implies that
$f(x_2) \le f(x_1)$.

Suppose there is an
$x^-$ such that
$f(x^-) < 0$.
Then
$f(x) \le f(x^-)$
for all $x > x^-$.
Therefore
$|f(x)| \ge |f(x^-)|$
for all $x \ge x^-$
which contradicts
$f(x) \to 0$.

Therefore
there is no $x$ such that
$f(x) < 0$.

Comment: I can't understand how the line "$|f(x)|\ge|f(x^-)| \forall x\ge x^-$" comes?

Comment: Because $f(x^-) < 0$. Then $f(x) \le f(x^-) < 0$ for a \ge x^-$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f $ is decreasing at $[1,+\infty) $ then

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f (x)=\inf_{[1,+\infty)}f=0$$

thus
$$\forall x\ge 1 \;\; f (x)\ge 0$$